# How to integrate the channel api into phonegap?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have coded two servlet(using the channel api) on gae that could make a connection f.ex.: for a chat
As UI I will use JqueryMobile.

My questions are:

- How to integrate the actions of the servlets into phonegap?
- Should I use any additional libaries or is it possible via action="...\servlet"(RESTful communication).
- Is there any best practice?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channels API relies on custom javascript that is downloaded from AppEngine when browser opens the page: [see javascript docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/javascript).

This custom JS code can potentially change when GAE version changes, so you can not embed it into your PhoneGap application. Also it possibly relies on browser-specific features, which is hard to check because it's a closed piece of code and it's internals are not explained.

If you need async notification, I'd suggest you use [native push](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/37159628/Notifications) technologies available on PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Channel API documentation.  It's all there.

You probably want to add an API to generate a new token in case your connection times out.  You also need to handle reconnection from the client in case you get disconnected (ie a socketerror event)